# Retrieve custom parameters using Google Analytics python api's

Tags: python, google-analytics

I defined custom dimensions in GA4 and I want to retrieve the data via Python. So under page_view, I defined custom parameters that have event count and total users associated with them. I have been fiddling with the code but I can't seem to get input parameters right. An example of a custom param is called n20_page_url. I want to know what pages got accessed each day.

My library's installed:
pip install --upgrade google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2  google-analytics-data

Here is the code I have so far, it successfully accesses built in dimensions and metrics. But that is not what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

**Start of program:**

```
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    RunReportRequest,
)
from google.oauth2 import service_account

import globals

SCOPES = globals.SCOPES
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = globals.KEY_FILE_LOCATION
PROPERTY_ID = globals.PROPERTY_ID

def sample_run_report():
 
    property_id = PROPERTY_ID

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)

    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient(credentials=credentials)
    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{PROPERTY_ID}",
        dimensions=[{"name": "date"}],
        metrics=[{"name": "activeUsers"}],
        date_ranges=[{"start_date": "7daysAgo", "end_date": "today"}]
    )
    response = client.run_report(request)
    print("Report result:")
    for row in response.rows:
        print(row.dimension_values[0].value, row.metric_values[0].value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample_run_report()
```

Comment: Per the [GA4 documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#custom_dimensions) have you tried `'customEvent:n20_page_url'`? Also, check out this as well: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/advanced#event-scoped_custom_dimensions